# rewrite apache httpd complete url with query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite url from one application to another application of diferent path with query string using below code of lines in my httpd.conf

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/rforms/jsp/rform/index.jsp?(.*)$ /Project/jsps/rform/indexAIL.jsp?$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^/rforms/onlineLandingPage.do?(.*)$ /Project/onlineLandingPage.do?pid=1&loginType=2&$1 [R]
```

url redirects but query string param get missed.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `RewriteRule` and **there is no real need to match query string here** since that will be carried over automatically.

Try these rules instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?rforms/jsp/rform/index\.jsp$ /Project/jsps/rform/indexAIL.jsp [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^/?rforms/onlineLandingPage\.do$ /Project/onlineLandingPage.do?pid=1&loginType=2 [R,L,NC,QSA]
```